# How to get limescale out of water?

Tags: water

I moved into a new place, the tap water here is good except for massive amounts of limescale.

Within a week every pot I have has formed a layer that takes half an hour of scrubbing to get off. It's annihilating my kettle and coffee machine and I don't even want to imagine what it's doing to my washing machine and dishwasher.
Is there an economic way to remove it from my tap water?

Comment: High mineral content in the water is indeed really problematic in cases of equipment used to boil or evaporate water. It will be less of a problem in your washing machine where the water is not normally boiled or evaporated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal answer would be to install a water softener; removing dissolved minerals is exactly what they're designed for.

A reverse-osmosis water filter might also do the job. I don't know whether they're available in sizes large enough to handle washing machines.

Comment: RO can be had in huge sizes - but economically, they are suited to drinking/cooking water use only for people with normal budgets. Water softeners are the more normal approach to everything else (they add a bit of sodium, which may or may not concern you in drinking water - RO is better from that point of view for drinking/cooking water.)